# Getting memory leak while using shared_ptr in a loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks, shared-ptr

I am getting memory leaks in below code I have used visual studio diagnostic tools to test this.

```
struct ChatMessage
{
    std::string senderName;
    std::string body;
    std::string messageId;
    ChatMessage()
    {
        senderName = "";
        body = "";
        messageId = "";
        
    }
}
typedef std::shared_ptr<ChatMessage> ChatMsgSharedPtr;

int main()
{
  for( some conditions)
  {
   ChatMsgSharedPtr chatMsgPtr = std::make_shared<ChatMessage>();
   chatMsgPtr->senderName = some value is assigned;
   chatMsgPtr->body= some value is assigned;
   chatMsgPtr->messageId= some value is assigned;
  }
return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me? I got a problem relating to memory leaks. I don't know how to solve it, can anyone can give some suggestions, it will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Ensure to post *compiling* code that shows the issue.

Comment: There's not enough information here to be able to do much to help. Why exactly do you think you have memory leaks? You certainly don't have them in the _exact_ code you're showing because this code won't even compile because you've glossed over a bunch of it. Without more information, people can at best guess what is actually going on in your actual code.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Yjnd31nM9 runs without leak. So, start from there, repro a leak and show us how you measured it and what you changed

Comment: OT: `senderName = "";` ... lines are not needed. The default constructor for std::string will construct a string that initialized to an empty sting.

Comment: Build it with `-g` and run it with `valgrind`. It will tell you exactly where the memory leak happens (i.e. what kind(s) of heap block(s) are leaked and what exact stack traces lead to their allocation earlier).

Comment: @SimranGehani There is no memory leak in the code you have shown, so any leak would have to be in code you have not shown.